# WCF streaming SQLFileStream by Message Contract

Tags: wcf

In my WCF service, I try to load a File from MS SQL table which has a FileStream column and I try to pass it as a stream back

```
        responseMsg.DocSqlFileStream = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            using (FileStreamDBEntities dbEntity = new FileStreamDBEntities())
            {
                ...
                using (TransactionScope x = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    string sqlCmdStr = "SELECT dcraDocFile.PathName() AS InternalPath, GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() AS TransactionContext FROM dcraDocument WHERE dcraDocFileID={0}";
                    var docFileStreamInfo = dbEntity.Database.SqlQuery<DocFileStreamPath>(sqlCmdStr, new object[] { docEntity.dcraDocFileID.ToString() }).First();

                    SqlFileStream sqlFS = new SqlFileStream(docFileStreamInfo.InternalPath, docFileStreamInfo.TransactionContext, FileAccess.Read);
                    sqlFS.CopyTo(responseMsg.DocSqlFileStream);

                    if( responseMsg.DocSqlFileStream.Length > 0 )
                        responseMsg.DocSqlFileStream.Position = 0;

                    x.Complete();
                }
            }
            ...
```

I'm wondering whats the best way to pass the SQLFileStream back through a message contract back to take advantage of streaming. Currently I copied the SQLFilEStream to a memory stream because I got an error message in WCF trace which says: Type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream' cannot be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

In WebApi there is such thing as `PushStreamContent` it allows delegating all transaction stuff to async lambda, don't know if there is something similar in WCF, but the following approach may be helpful:

http://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/archive/2012/12/12/asynchronous-streaming-in-asp-net-webapi.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can't stream an SQLFileStream back to the client because it can only be read within the SQL transaction. I think your solution with the MemoryStream is a good way of dealing with the problem.

I had a similar problem and was worried about the large object heap when using a new Memory Stream every time. I came up with the idea of using a temporary file on the disk instead of a memory stream. We are using this solution in several project now and it works really well.

See here for the example code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11307324/173711

Comment: Thanks for your idea and sharing your solution in the link, may be I keep it as is for now, the message contract which I created is I IDisposable and the dispose method can help to release the memory stream (which actually a Stream in msg contract) after reading in caller side. But your temp file solution is definitely an approach too.